# How to remove ellipses when calling repr for large strings in python

Tags: python

I would like to understand the behavoir of the `repr` function in python. If I run

```
print(repr('1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'))
print(len(repr('1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111')))
```

I get as output

```
'111111111111...1111111111111'
30
```

Furthermore, if I define a class `ptuple`

```
class ptuple(tuple):

    def __repr__(self):
        return '(' + ','.join( repr(x)  for x in self) + ')'
```

and I run the following lines:

```
a = tuple(('holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'chao', 'verde', 'rojo'))
b = ptuple(('holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'chao', 'verde', 'rojo'))
print(repr(a))
print(repr(b))
```

I obtain

```
('holaaaaaaaaa...aaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'chao', 'verde', 'rojo')
('holaaaaaaaa...verde','rojo')
```

Could someone please explain to me what is happening under the hood, why could this behavoir be more desirable than obtaining the full representation I would have otherwise expected (over 30 characters long) and maybe how can I force the output to be the full representation without ellipses?

I hope my question is clear, thank you.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What version of Python are you using? It's working fine on versions 3.7.2 and 2.7.12

Comment: I cannot reproduce the result. What is your environment?

Comment: This is the behavior of [reprlib.repr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/reprlib.html#reprlib.Repr.maxstring). Are you sure that you haven't overwritten the default `repr` with `reprlib.repr`?

Comment: Oh, I see now I unknowingly imported a module in my script (that I didn't include in this code) that did actually replace `repr` with `reprlib.repr`... I've been looking for it for days, I'm really sorry and thank you very much!